# A create view in another view django

Tags: django, django-views

I am new to django. I've created a basic posts app where users post messages. The project has posts app for posting messages. The app has two models- Post and Comment where one post can have many comments. My posts are shown in list view with comments for a particular post.

Now, i want to have an 'add comment' button for each post so i can directly add comment (stack exchange design!) . This can otherwise be implemented by a seperate createview for comments model. I want an textarea on listview itself to input comments for a post.

How can i do this?

Comment: Just pass a form to the page, and let the request redirect to the `CreateView`.

Comment: Thanks but can you help me out how to do this?

Comment: Being new to django, i don't know how do i do that. Pls help me

Answer (score 0):

In the most basic form, you can define different routes for your desired views (`CreateComment`, `PostDetails`) and send a `POST` request to the `CreateComment` view from the `PostDetails` route.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<pk>/', post_details, name='post-details'),
    path('comment/new/', add_comment, name='create-comment'),
]
```

and in your `post/<pk>/` route, set up a form like below:

```
<form method="POST" action="/comment/new/">
    <input value="" name="description" type="text" />
    <input value="/current/path/" name="redirect" type="hidden" />
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

You can then redirect the user to the page he was making the request from in the first place, using the `redirect` value which is passed by the form from the origin route.